# IF IS NULL then SINGLE else keep the value of the field

Tags: ms-access

I am working with a DB in Access and I'd like to be able to fill the field in this row with a result of SINGLE if it is not already filled with another value.

I wrote Iif(MaritalStatus) is null, "SINGLE") but Access returned a result in which all of the fields were filled with SINGLE except those that had had a previous value of Married, Divorced, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
NZ(MaritalStatus,"SINGLE")
```

> From [Nz Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx) in the documentation:
>
> You can use the **Nz** function to return zero, a zero-length string (" "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null. For example, you can use this function to convert a **Null** value to another value and prevent it from propagating through an expression.

Or you can use:

```
IIF(IsNull(MaritalStatus),"SINGLE",MaritalStatus)
```