# VB.Net error with CASE SELECT

Tags: ms-access

The following VB.Net code runs fine on SQL Server but gives an error on Access:

```vb
sql = "SELECT sr.itemcode, sr.itemname, SUM(CASE WHEN sr.transdate='4/14/2016' THEN sr.temunits] END) AS [Units Sold], " & _
      "SUM(sr.itemunits) AS [Total Units Sold] " & _
      "FROM [tblINV_SalesRecord] AS sr WHERE sr.transdate <= '4/14/2016' GROUP BY sr.itemcode, sr.itemname"
```

The error is:

> ```
> IErrorInfo.GetDescription Failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005), -System.Data
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access does not support CASE expressions. The most generic equivalent would be the [Switch function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379). Using that function, a SQL CASE expression like this

```
CASE
  WHEN condition1 THEN value1
  WHEN condition2 THEN value2
  ...
END
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
Switch(
  condition1, value1,
  condition2, value2,
  ...
)
```

A more specific, and probably more appropriate for your situation, equivalent is the [IIf function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/IIf-Function-32436ECF-C629-48A3-9900-647539C764E3). It is intended for use when you need to return one of two values based on a single condition. In other words, it replaces the following CASE pattern:

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN true_value ELSE false_value END
```

and goes like this:

```
IIf(condition, true_value, false_value)
```

In your particular situation, the CASE expression does not have an ELSE clause. That means that `ELSE NULL` is implied, although `ELSE 0` may be more appropriate here. So, you can rewrite the query like this:

```
sql = "SELECT sr.itemcode, sr.itemname, " & _
             "SUM(IIf(sr.transdate='4/14/2016', sr.temunits, 0)) AS [Units Sold], " & _
             "SUM(sr.itemunits) AS [Total Units Sold] " & _
      "FROM [tblINV_SalesRecord] AS sr WHERE sr.transdate <= '4/14/2016' " & _
      "GROUP BY sr.itemcode, sr.itemname"
```

Comment: How do I ensure  SUM(sr.itemunits) returns 0 in the case of NULL??

Comment: @Smarton: [IF IS NULL then SINGLE else keep the value of the field](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66498/if-is-null-then-single-else-keep-the-value-of-the-field). In your case, it could be `SUM(Nz(sr.itemunits, 0))` or `SUM(IIf(IsNull(sr.itemunits), 0, sr.itemunits))`, although, to be honest, I don't really understand why store NULL at all in such cases. But of course I don't know all the details, maybe there's a good reason for that.